# React Native: Null is not an object - Push notification (OneSignal)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, state, onesignal

I am facing a problem with my push notifications at the moment.. I am trying to init OneSignal in my repo and I have followed the OneSignal installation guide and double checked it already. Everything is set up correctly!

However, I have two problems which are different on iOS and on Android. There are three ways to receive a push notification:

- Case 1: The app is opened
- Case 2: The app has been open, has been closed (not killed) and is still running in the background
- Case 3: The app is not open and is not running in the background (has been killed/swiped off the screen)

iOS:
On my iPhone case 1 and case 2 are working perfectly without any issue. However, in case 3 my application is showing this screen (images attached below).

Android:
On Android phones case 1 and 3 is working without any problems but in case 2 the app is not displaying my popup dialog.. But also is not crashing and running!

So, I think, like the iOS screen is telling me, there is somewhere a problem with my state cause it's `null`. However, in my eyes is still confusing cause exactly this case is working in Android...

However, I am using the functions and `EventHandler` given in the OneSignal documentation. Also, I am using a library called `react-native-popup-dialog` to show a popup when sending a push notification. This popup is only visible if I send certain key/value pairs with the push notification. These keys are:

1. `showPopup`:`true` - Displaying the popup when true. If it isn't set or not equals true, it isn't displayed!
2. `openLink`:`mydomain.de`- Adds a button with a link to the popup
3. `buttonText`:`Open in Browser` - Sets the button text to the link

> Note, the extra URL button is only added to the popup if key `openLink` and `buttonText` is set. Of none of them or only one of the key is set, it isn't displaying this button.

So far so good. So, here is my source code now and I hope you guys can help me out.. trying to debug this since 3 days...

> Note, the method getPopup() get's called by several (different) screens which are extending this (SuperScreen) class.

```
import Dialog, { SlideAnimation, DialogTitle, DialogContent, DialogButton } from "react-native-popup-dialog";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import OneSignal from "react-native-onesignal"

export default class SuperScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pushNotification: null,
      visible: false
    };

    OneSignal.setLogLevel(6, 0);
    OneSignal.init("00000000000000000000000000000000000", {
      kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: true
    });

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(0);
    OneSignal.enableVibrate(true);
    OneSignal.enableSound(true);

    OneSignal.addEventListener("received", this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("received", this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("opened", this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener("ids", this.onIds);
  }

  onReceived = notification => {
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification);

    this.setState({
      pushNotification: notification,
      visible: true
    });

    if (this.state.pushNotification.payload.notificationID != null) {
      firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
        notificationID: this.state.pushNotification.payload.notificationID,
        clicked: true
      });
    }
  };

  onOpened = openResult => {
    console.log("Message: ", openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log("Data: ", openResult.notification.payload.additionalData);
    console.log("isActive: ", openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log("openResult: ", openResult);

    this.setState({
      pushNotification: openResult.notification,
      visible: true
    });

    if (this.state.pushNotification.payload.notificationID != null) {
      firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
        notificationID: this.state.pushNotification.payload.notificationID,
        clicked: true
      });
    }
  };

  onIds = device => {
    console.log("Device info: ", device);
  };

  getPopup() {
    if (
      this.state.pushNotification != null &&
      this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData != null &&
      this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.showPopup != null &&
      this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.showPopup == "true"
    ) {
      var actionButtons = null;

      if (
        this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.openLink != null &&
        this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.buttonText != null
      ) {
        actionButtons = [
          <DialogButton
            text="Ok"
            key={0}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ visible: false });
              firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
                notificationID: this.state.pushNotification.payload
                  .notificationID,
                opened: false
              });
            }}
          />
        ];

        actionButtons.push(
          <DialogButton
            text={this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.buttonText}
            key={1}
            onPress={() => {
              this.openLink(
                this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData.openLink
              );
              this.setState({ visible: false });
              firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
                notificationID: this.state.pushNotification.payload
                  .notificationID,
                link: this.state.pushNotification.payload.additionalData
                  .openLink,
                opened: true
              });
            }}
          />
        );
      } else {
        actionButtons = [
          <DialogButton
            text="Ok"
            key={0}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({ visible: false, pushNotification: null });
              firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
                popupID: this.state.pushNotification.payload.notificationID,
                opened: false
              });
            }}
          />
        ];
      }

      return (
        <Dialog
          visible={this.state.visible == null ? false : this.state.visible}
          dialogTitle={
            <DialogTitle
              title={
                this.state.pushNotification == null
                  ? ""
                  : this.state.pushNotification.payload.title
              }
            />
          }
          dialogAnimation={
            new SlideAnimation({
              slideFrom: "bottom"
            })
          }
          dialogStyle={{ marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20 }}
          actions={actionButtons}
        >
          <DialogContent>
            <Text />
            <Text>
              {this.state.pushNotification == null
                ? ""
                : this.state.pushNotification.payload.body}
            </Text>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      );
    }
  }
```

**My iPhone images:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a value from state that hasn’t been set. Setting state is an asynchronous action so there is no guarantee that it will be set by the time you call it.

You should use the notification object directly and not the one you set to state.

You can learn more about setting state here

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0

Here is an example of what I am meaning.

```
onReceived = notification => {
    console.log("Notification received: ", notification);

    this.setState({
      pushNotification: notification,
      visible: true
    });
    // use the actual notification object instead of this.state.pushNotification. 
    if (notification.payload.notificationID != null) {
      firebase.analytics().logEvent("Popup_Link_Button", {
        notificationID: notification.payload.notificationID,
        clicked: true
      });
    }
  };
```

You will also need to update the onOpened function too

Comment: However, the popup is still not showing up on my iOS device but on my Android device it is for case 3!

Comment: As you are using state to within your popup there may be another case where it is getting called before the state has been set. Perhaps passing the values as parameters to the function `getPopUp` may solve that issue. But you haven’t shown how that function is called. Another option maybe that iOS isn’t receiving the values from the notification, you should check these.

Comment: I cannot pass them to the function directly cause they get called from a subclass which is extending this class. However, as you can see in the first line of `getPopup()` -> I am checking the state with the if statement. Also, the popup should always be updated when the state is update (so, afterwards - there shouldn't be a problem)!

Comment: But setState is asynchronous so it may not have finished being set by the time getPopUp is called. That means `this.state.visible` may still be false meaning that it doesn’t show the popup

Comment: But `getPopup(..)` is always invisible when starting the app. It is only set to visible AFTER a push notification got send and received AND I have set the state to visible and set the state of pushNotification. So it is basically rendering itself!

Comment: ALSO: Even more strange is the fact that the popup is showing up on Android when the app is completely closed but it isn't showing up on iOS. But, when the app is operating in the background (so, not completely closed), the popup shows up in iOS but not on Android.. Isn't that strange AF..?